# Populate array inside nested foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code. In the last foreach I'd like to add `$last_array` and `$last2_array` as key/value pairs inside `$display` array. Here's what I tried:

```
$display[] = array($last_array => $last2_array); //doesn't work
print_r($display); //under the loop prints nothing
```

The code:

```
$display=array();//declare the array outside the loop
foreach ($array as $arrays){ 
    foreach ($arrays as $elem) {
        unset($elem['id']); //Removes id key
        unset($elem['idno']); //Removes idno key
        foreach ($elem as $last_array => $last2_array) {
            //code here                       
            #echo $last_array. ": ".$last2_array."<br>";//This prints data, it's not empty.
        }       
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to edit an array while looping with foreach, use `&`: `foreach ($array as &$arrays){`

Comment: your array `$display` prints blank so how will it work anyway? how are you constructing the array `$display`?

Comment: @amigura: I tried with this code inside the last loop: $display[] = array($last_array => $last2_array); This doesn't work

Comment: just a guess. `$display=array(1,2,3);`  you want to add 4 and 5 `array_push($display, 4, 5);`
 [array push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: what is `$array` data?

Comment: @amigura A print_r($array):Array ( [ok] => 1 [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [object_id] => 13 [id] => 13 [idno] => e00110-o00005-2010-PROG [display_label] => La Bohème / PUCCINI - 2010 [ca_objects.description] => Libreto de Luigi Illica y Giuseppe Giacosa basado en Escenas de la vida bohemia de Henri Murger Nueva producción – Teatro Colón [ca_objects.type_id] => Programa de mano )  . This is just one of 548 elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$display=array();//declare the array outside the loop
foreach ($array as $arrays){ 
    foreach ($arrays as $elem) {
        unset($elem['id']); //Removes id key
        unset($elem['idno']); //Removes idno key
        foreach ($elem as $last_array => $last2_array) {
          $display[$last_array] = $last2_array;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this will work! I'm having a strange issue, if I add your line of code I get this error from apache: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/search2.php on line 33. Line 33 Is the first foreach loop. If I replace your line with  echo   $last_array.$last2_array."<br>";. It prints data just fine with no errors. Guess I'll have to do some debugging!

Comment: It just got weirder... In order for your line to work I have to let the line that echoes the results, otherwise I get the error above and $display appears empty. I if leave the echo line in place print_r(display); shows only the last element from $last2_array. Array ( [object_id] => 549 [display_label] => test [ca_objects.description] => [ca_objects.type_id] => Audio )

Comment: maybe one of these is not an array but an object: $array, $arrays, $elem

Comment: This code gathers all elements:  $display[] = array($last_array => $last2_array); But not in the way I want, it makes an array of each value. A print_r($display) portion: Array ( [0] => Array ( [object_id] => 13 ) [1] => Array ( [display_label] => La Bohème / PUCCINI - 2010 ) [2] => Array ( [ca_objects.description]. It's late here, guess I'll find it out after a good night sleep! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you do a search on **Multidimensional Arrays** to learn abit more on creating and accessing them.

```
$object_id=$array['results'][0]['object_id'];
$display_label=$array['results'][0]['display_label'];

$display = array($object_id => $display_label);
print_r($display);
```

Comment: I like that... I'll check the code later, thanks! I've been doing some serious reading but I'm too tired now, thanks again! I'll let you know the results.